# TeamCity 8.1 MSTest fails every time

Tags: teamcity, mstest

I have 4 unit test that fails every time in TeamCity.
What does this tests do is load 2 text files (embedded resources so it is not a path problem) and compare them, so they do string comparison.
Test fails on Assert.AreEqual(str1, str2).
I tried to copy one file to the other one (they are identical).
The same tests pass on every other machine in Visual Studio/Resharper test runner.

Tests are done in Visual Studio 2013, using MSTest framework. On .Net version 4.5, Platform Release/Any CPU
I tried MSTest Runner 2013 and VSTest Console plugin and I get the same result.

Comment: Can you share the actual test?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my string filed. in str1 there was "\n" as Environment.NewLine, but in str2 there was "\r\n" as Environment.NewLine

Comment: that explains what happened but not how you fixed it. so what did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a string compare also fail only in Teamcity, I just removed the newline characters from both, like this:

```
 var expected = originalExpected.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
 var actual = originalActual.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
 Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```